# In Mongo DB Getting Whole collection of date even if one is matched inside it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In Mongo DB Getting Whole collection of date even if one is matched inside it.

Creating a new Collection with the below data:

```
db.details.insert({
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "johnson",
    "dates": [
        {"date": ISODate("2016-05-01")},
        {"date": ISODate("2016-08-01")}
    ]
})
```

Fetching Back:

```
db.details.find().pretty()
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Johnson",
    "dates": [
        {"date": ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00Z")},
        {"date": ISODate("2016-08-01T00:00:00Z")}
    ]
}
```

So here there is a collection called dates inside another collection details.

Now I want to filter the date inside dates using Greater than and want the result showing `"2016-08-01"`.

But when I search like the following:

```
db.details.find(
    {"dates.date": {$gt: ISODate("2016-07-01")}},
    {"dates.date": 1, "_id": 0}
).pretty()
```

Getting the Result as below, Its giving me the entire collection even if one date is matched in it:

```
{
    "dates": [
        {"date": ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00Z")},
        {"date": ISODate("2016-08-01T00:00:00Z")}
    ]
}
```

Please help in getting the Expected data, i.e.:

```
{
  "date": ISODate("2016-08-01T00:00:00Z")
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregate framework for this:

```
db.details.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$dates'},
    {$match: {'dates.date': {$gt: ISODate("2016-07-01")}}}, 
    {$project: {_id: 0, 'dates.date': 1}}
]);
```

**Another way (Works only for mongo 3.2):**

```
db.details.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        _id: 0, 
        dates: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$dates', 
                as: 'item', 
                cond: {
                    $gte: ['$$item.date', ISODate('2016-08-01T00:00:00Z')]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

**To only return the date field:**

```
db.details.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$dates'},
    {$match: {'dates.date': {$gt: ISODate('2016-07-01')}}}, 
    {$group: {_id: '$dates.date'}}, 
    {$project: {_id: 0, date: '$_id'}}
]);
```

Returns:

```
{ 
  "date" : ISODate("2016-08-01T00:00:00Z") 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works perfectly.